# Enabling textbox on button click event

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

How can i add the mechanism in my downloader for the case although many threads on SO deals either with php etc and not upto the need.

> I have a browse button at the front of a textbox where i get's the user entered Path on local drive to fix the location for downloading but i have already hardcoded one for system drive.I want textbox button to be disabled unless user clciks browse button and then new path can be entered for downloading after then.

How can i go?

Answer (score 0):

A quick example:

```
private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var saveFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
        var selectedPath= saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (selectedPath == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _savePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Text = _savePath;
        }
    }
```